# Hide a custom ajax component in jsf when in its own value is changed

Tags: jsf, richfaces, conditional-rendering, ajax-update

I have a custom ajax combobox component. When the value within it is changed, I want to hide the combobox and show a label in it's place. I tried doing it using the render attribute for the combobox and the h:outputText. It kind of worked but the browser gives this error:

> Error while processiong request. Details: Dom element: ppForm:workItemsTree:0:1:1:assignee_:assignee_setValue RequestStatus:Notfound

The assignee setValue is a method called on combobox change
Why is the browser still trying to locate the combobox when its render attribute is set to false?

**Update:**

The combo box component is a facelet template and it has dynamic ids. The dynamic part of id is missing (after "_" and I have represented as MISSING_ID_PART for your reference) while rendering, as can be seen from the following.

> ppForm:workItemsTree:0:1:1:assignee_:assignee_setValu
>   ppForm:workItemsTree:0:1:1:assignee_MISSING_ID_PART:assignee_MISSING_ID_PARTsetValue

Using richfaces 4.2.2 with myfaces 2.1

**In general, is it possible to initiate ajax request from one component and not render that component but render some other component ? If yes, pls share how to do it or any workarounds ways to achieve the same.**

Comment: If you want to know what's wrong with your code you have to show it, what version of RichFaces are you using?

Comment: Because **component should be built before rendering**. If component is not rendered is does not mean it is not built.